# Mocking nested promises with jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

The function that I am creating a test on uses a nested promises and cannot be converted to async await right now

```
exports.createCampaign = (req, res) => {
  const { name } = req.body;
  User.findByPk(req.userId).then((user) => {
    Account.findOne({ where: { id: user.accountId } }).then((account) => {
      Campaign.create({
        accountId: account.id,
        name: name,
        uuid: uuid.v4(),
      })
        .then((campaign) => {
          if (campaign) {
            return res.status(201).json({
              id: campaign.id,
              name: campaign.name,
              uuid: campaign.uuid,
            });
          }
          return res.status(500).send({ message: 'Campaign not created' });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          return res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });
        });
    });
  });
};
```

This is how I test it

```
jest.mock('@545490/kgr-models', () => ({
  user: {
    findByPk: jest.fn(),
  },
  account: {
    findOne: jest.fn(),
  },
  campaign: {
    create: jest.fn(),
    findOne: jest.fn(),
  },
}));

describe('CampaignController', () => {
  let mockStatus, mockJson, mockRes, mockSend;
  mockJson = jest.fn();
  mockSend = jest.fn();
  mockStatus = jest.fn(() => ({ json: mockJson, send: mockSend }));
  mockRes = { status: mockStatus };

  const mockUser = {
    id: 'userId',
    firstName: 'firstName',
    lastName: 'lastName',
    email: 'email',
    accountId: 'accountId',
  };
  const mockAccount = {
    id: 'accountId',
    name: 'accountName',
    partner: 'partner',
  };
  const mockCampaign = {
    id: 'campaignId',
    name: 'campaignName',
    accountId: 'accountId',
    status: 'active',
  };

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  describe('createCampaign', () => {
    it('should create a campaign', async () => {
     
      User.findByPk.mockResolvedValue(mockUser);
      Account.findOne.mockResolvedValue(mockAccount);
      Campaign.create.mockResolvedValue(mockCampaign);

      await createCampaign({
        body: {
          name: 'campaignName',
        },
        userId: 'userId',
      }, mockRes);

      expect(User.findByPk).toHaveBeenCalledWith('userId');
      expect(Account.findOne).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ where: { id: mockUser.accountId } });
      expect(Campaign.create).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(mockStatus).toHaveBeenCalledWith(201);
      expect(mockJson).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

After I ran the test it fails and gives me this message
[image]

I thought maybe its related to the nested promises which I don't think I have correctly mocked since I tried to convert it to async await and it works correctly. Right now, I am not allowed to update the function so I need to test the function as it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return each promise so that you can use `async/await` to wait for the promise chain accomplished. See [chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#chaining)

`models.js`:

```js
const User = {
    findByPk() {},
};

const Account = {
    findOne() {},
};

const Campaign = {
    create() {},
    findOne() {},
};

module.exports = { User, Account, Campaign };
```

`controller.js`:

```js
const { User, Account, Campaign } = require('./models');

exports.createCampaign = async (req, res) => {
    const { name } = req.body;
    return User.findByPk(req.userId).then((user) => {
        return Account.findOne({ where: { id: user.accountId } }).then((account) => {
            return Campaign.create({
                accountId: account.id,
                name: name,
                // uuid: uuid.v4(),
            })
                .then((campaign) => {
                    if (campaign) {
                        return res.status(201).json({
                            id: campaign.id,
                            name: campaign.name,
                            uuid: campaign.uuid,
                        });
                    }
                    return res.status(500).send({ message: 'Campaign not created' });
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    return res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });
                });
        });
    });
};
```

`controller.test.js`:

```js
const { createCampaign } = require('./controller');
const { User, Account, Campaign } = require('./models');


jest.mock('./models', () => ({
    User: {
        findByPk: jest.fn(),
    },
    Account: {
        findOne: jest.fn(),
    },
    Campaign: {
        create: jest.fn(),
        findOne: jest.fn(),
    },
}));

describe('CampaignController', () => {
    let mockStatus, mockJson, mockRes, mockSend;
    mockJson = jest.fn();
    mockSend = jest.fn();
    mockStatus = jest.fn(() => ({ json: mockJson, send: mockSend }));
    mockRes = { status: mockStatus };

    const mockUser = {
        id: 'userId',
        firstName: 'firstName',
        lastName: 'lastName',
        email: 'email',
        accountId: 'accountId',
    };
    const mockAccount = {
        id: 'accountId',
        name: 'accountName',
        partner: 'partner',
    };
    const mockCampaign = {
        id: 'campaignId',
        name: 'campaignName',
        accountId: 'accountId',
        status: 'active',
    };

    afterEach(() => {
        jest.clearAllMocks();
    });

    describe('createCampaign', () => {
        it('should create a campaign', async () => {
            User.findByPk.mockResolvedValue(mockUser);
            Account.findOne.mockResolvedValue(mockAccount);
            Campaign.create.mockResolvedValue(mockCampaign);

            await createCampaign(
                {
                    body: {
                        name: 'campaignName',
                    },
                    userId: 'userId',
                },
                mockRes,
            );

            expect(User.findByPk).toHaveBeenCalledWith('userId');
            expect(Account.findOne).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ where: { id: mockUser.accountId } });
            expect(Campaign.create).toHaveBeenCalled();
            expect(mockStatus).toHaveBeenCalledWith(201);
            expect(mockJson).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/77184534/controller.test.js (5.559 s)
  CampaignController
    createCampaign
      ✓ should create a campaign (2 ms)

---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File           | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files      |   81.82 |       50 |   83.33 |      80 |                   
 controller.js |   81.82 |       50 |   83.33 |      80 | 20-23             
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.785 s, estimated 6 s
```